# Boost c++ library, linker failed with Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, boost, linker, filesystems

I am trying to use boost in my c++ Xcode project so I wrote this simple code for read names of files in folder.

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
struct path_leaf_string
{
    std::string operator()(const boost::filesystem::directory_entry& entry) const {
        return entry.path().leaf().string();
    }
};

int main(){
    std::string name = ".";
    std::vector< std::string> v;
    boost::filesystem::path p(name);
    boost::filesystem::directory_iterator start(p);
    boost::filesystem::directory_iterator end;
    std::transform(start, end, std::back_inserter(v), path_leaf_string());
}
```

Of course I use in header search path `/usr/local/include`, in library search paths `/usr/local/lib` where boost has been installed and in other linker flags I type `-lboost_system` or I keep it empty. 
But the linker still returns this error.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
    "boost::filesystem::detail::dir_itr_close(void*&, void*&)", referenced from:
        boost::filesystem::detail::dir_itr_imp::~dir_itr_imp() in main.o
    "boost::filesystem::detail::directory_iterator_construct(boost::filesystem::directory_iterator&, boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)", referenced from:
        boost::filesystem::directory_iterator::directory_iterator(boost::filesystem::path const&) in main.o
    "boost::filesystem::detail::directory_iterator_increment(boost::filesystem::directory_iterator&, boost::system::error_code*)", referenced from:
        boost::filesystem::directory_iterator::increment() in main.o
    "boost::system::generic_category()", referenced from:
        boost::system::error_category::std_category::equivalent(int, std::__1::error_condition const&) const in main.o
        boost::system::error_category::std_category::equivalent(std::__1::error_code const&, int) const in main.o
    "boost::filesystem::path::filename() const", referenced from:
        boost::filesystem::path::leaf() const in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I use Xcode 9.2 and macOS HighSierra.
Also I tried all recommended solutions on Stackoverflow but still not working.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: add `-lboost_filesystem`